# c++ - other way of implementing function calls in switch cases

Tags: c++, templates, boost, stl

I've got code below:

```
void CashFlow::execute (int cmd)
{
    switch(cmd):
    {
        case BUY:
            BuyProc ();
            break;
        case SELL:
            SellProc ();
            break;
         ......
    }
}
```

What I'm thinking of doing is maybe create a map like `std::map <int, void (CashFlow::*)()> CashflowProcs;`

Then maybe use mCashFlowProcs = boost::assign::map_list_of (BUY, &CashFlow::BuyProc)(...etc)(..Etc.);

Then I can call it like `(this->(mCashFlowProcs [cmd]))()`;

How do I turn this into template so it can be reused? Could there be issues with this implementation?

Note that I am not using C++11

Comment: `boost::unordered_map<cmd_enum, boost::function<void()>>`?

Comment: Although I would probably just use a regular table.

Comment: What I don't understand is "How do I turn this into a template so it can be reused"?  What are you asking here?  Did you want to template this concept on the `CashflowProcs` type?

Comment: @MooingDuck That looks like it's of the order of three indirections plus hashing minus inlining and potentially cache-misses o.O

Comment: @dyp: But that is significantly _less_ than what the OP is proposing, which is `log n + C` indirections minus inlining.  A regular array would have no real indirection, but also no inlining.

Comment: Most likely this will not give You any performance benifit as the compiler will translate the switch into a jump table anyway

Comment: My version of boost doesn't have unordered map.

Comment: I agree a regular array should be the first choice. Never sure about `map`s vs `unordered_map`s and boost::function vs function ptr..

Comment: It's funny how C++ programmers always try to micro-optimize. OP didn't ask about a fast way to do it, it sounds more like a question on how to do it more *elegant*. IMHO, as long as performance isn't very important, the most elegant way should be the *first choice*.

Comment: @mooing duck I wanted to make it more generic to use for other classes.

Comment: @kunkka_71: Boost has had unorderd_map for a very long time.  Can you clarify what version of boost you have, or do you not have access to all of it?

Comment: @leemes If the enum values are (almost) contiguous, why not use an array of function pointers? -- That information is missing in the question. (I'm rather trying to get rid of `map`s, not trying to micro-optimize)

Comment: @dyp IMHO, that *is* the most elegant way, but the argument was performance, which it should not be. In other words, a map is as elegant as an array.

Comment: Sorry. I'm more of a python programmer so my approach might be similar.

Comment: @leemes If both are (can) be similarly elegant, why not use the faster one?

Comment: @leemes Oh, wait, I'm actually not a performance advocate :D just trying to think about alternatives for maps atm.

Comment: @dyp Well, it depends on the case if arrays or a map (or maybe a vector) is the more/most elegant way, but a map would be more dynamic. If OP wants to add commands via some runtime mechanism (maybe in the future), you can't use an array, for example. And the more I think about the question, the more I think a good old switch is the most elegant way if the set of functions is more or less static, and if you only have to list them once in your code. But OP asked about alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could there be issues with this implementation?

Yes, it is hard to maintain, as adding/removing Command would need a lot of maintenance, would be error prone, and difficult to test. So I suggest a design change before trying to just improve this particular code.

**1 - If you can change your design:**

Use a `class` to represent a Command

```
class Command
{
    public:
        virtual void Execute() = 0;
        virtual ~Command() {};;
};

class BuyCommand : public Command
{
    public:
        virtual void Execute() { cout << "BUY"; }
};

class SellCommand : public Command
{
    public:
        virtual void Execute() { cout << "SELL"; }
};

// ...
Command* bc = new BuyCommand();
// ...
bc->Execute();
```

**2 - If (unfortunately) you cant change design that way**

If the `cmd` enumeration is known at compile time, and has a limited size, you can use an array of `boost::function`, and you should definitely regroup your command in an `enum` instead of using an `int`.

```
enum { BUY = 0; SELL = 1; NB_CMDS= 2 };
...
boost::array<NB_CMDS, boost::function<void()>>  // N is the number of commands.
```

indexing your array with, cmd, you simply call the function that has the index `cmd` in this array.

If you don't know at compile time how many commands/functions you will need, you might need to replace the array by a `std::vector`.

If one day you can use C++11, replace `boost::` by `std::` in the above snippets.

Comment: Looks like a design change is best.